# Responsive bootstrap panel header with buttons?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some advice to make bootstrap panel header responsive. Panel has title with several buttons on the right side. It looks fine in large screen but looks ugly when browser size is small.

My full code here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NogerbekNurzhan/8x6yg554/1/).

```css
.panel {
  margin: 15px;
}

.panel-title {
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mr-10 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-success panel-br-4">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">
      <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>Documents</span>
    </h4>
    <a id="document-сreate-btn" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
      <span>Create new document</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning pull-right mr-10">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning pull-right mr-10">
      <span>Save new order</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">Some content</div>
</div>
```

When all items cannot fit in one line, I want to make header as in the next picture:
[image]

Is such things makes by flexbox or bootstrap grid system? Whats the better way? I will appreciate any examples! :)

Comment: Bootstrap's grid system would be a good approach. Give it a try and let us know if you have issues.

Comment: Hello @sean :) The problem with bootstrap grid system is that order based on browser screen even if items fit in one line. I think better way is flexbox I have style when items cannot fit in one line but I don't have ideas how to trigger it. In post by the way you can see that css code.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap grid system (rows and columns), and that would be the easiest way to achieve your goal. If you want to be more exact with how you display your elements, you will need to use media queries. You don't necessarily need to use flex box (although I really like it). Bootstrap grid system is nothing more than "out of the box" media queries .

Comment: @LuizChagasJr Hello! I am try to use grid system but results are not good. Can you show me your example if it possible please?!

Comment: Thats what I try with grid system. But I have some problems with title also buttons don't so to next line when no space: https://jsfiddle.net/NogerbekNurzhan/8x6yg554/5/

Comment: Nurzhan, can you edit your question to include the code from jsfiddle in it? That way, others may benefit from this question too. (External links can go dead over time).

Comment: @sean Hello, bro! :) I update my posy with code from jsfiddle as you advised. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Also I have variant with grid system but it works bad:  https://jsfiddle.net/NogerbekNurzhan/8x6yg554/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick example of how to use Bootstrap grid system. It's not gonna be as perfect as you want but it will give you an introduction to grid systems. Also, don't forget to read about media queries.

```
<div class="panel panel-success panel-br-4">
 <div class="panel-heading">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>Documents</span>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: flex">
         <a class="btn btn-warning mr-10">
         <span>Save new order</span>
         </a>
         <a class="btn btn-warning">
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <a id="document-сreate-btn" class="btn btn-success mr-10" data-url="">
         <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
         <span>Create new document</span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Hello! :) Not quite elegant solution. It needs multiple changes but anyway thanks!